# HTML from one page to div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button that, when clicked, gets contents from another page and puts the content from that page in a `div`. The page that it gets the content from has additional code that makes the text fade after it has been displayed. But, when it gets the contents from that page it does not bring over that portion too. Is there a way that either in the code, below, or on the page it gets the contents from make the text fade out once it is displayed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name=buttonup53]").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"add.php?r=sbt&l=35&t=53&w=1", success:function(result){
    $("div[id=up53]").html(result);
  }});
});});
</script>
<div id="up53"></div>
<input type="image" name="buttonup53" id="buttonup53" src="button.png" width="25px"></input>
```

Comment: As a side curiosity, why use `div[id=up53]` as opposed to `#up53`?

Comment: Using `div[id=53]` as opposed to `#up53` is roughly 90% slower (source: http://jsperf.com/id-equals-vs-id). Please stop using it if you care for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you can use a setTimeout in the success callback to make the div fade away.

```
$.ajax({
 url:'',
 ...
 success:function(result){
    $("#up53").html(result);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#up53").fadeOut('slow');},2000);
 }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the `fadeout` to `fadeOut`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use load() method of jquery.  [Jquery Load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
  $("Div#up53").load("add.php?r=sbt&l=35&t=53&w=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("div[id=up53]").html(result).fadeOut();
```